# Custom user registration in Django

Tags: django, registration

I am somehow struggling to find a way to register a user in Django.

I want to accept user's first name, last name, email address (to use as username) and password and confirmation password to check for typo.

I have made a form class

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    firstname =  forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First name'}), label="Firstname", required=True)
    lastname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last name'}), label="Lastname", required=True)
    username = forms.EmailField(required=True, label='Email')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}), label="Password", required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
```

This form needs to be displayed in my index page. (Like facebook)

I read at least a dozen guides to make this happen but somehow it does not even pass form validation.

I have the following code for my view

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect("registered.html")
        else:
            print(user_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form' : user_form});
```

Do you guys have any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: What are the validation errors that you get?

Comment: Where can I see it? I can only see that it's taking me to the wrong page. Debugging told me that it doesn't pass the validation

Comment: I forgot to include {{form.error}} in my template. It says date_joined and last_login is required

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. fixed this myself...
But thank you Vasily  for leading me there :)

turns out I needed to include

```
fields = ('firstname','lastname','username','password')
```

inside the Meta class of UserForm class

Comment: The only thing that I wanted to note is that you don't in fact need the `password` field, because you don't want to save the password that the user enters in your DB, you want to put a hash of it there (and you do it by `user.set_password(user.password)`). So you should remove the `password` from the `fields` (but leave it in the form).

Comment: Well and change `user.set_password(user.password)` (it's completely wrong to do it like this) to `user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])`

Comment: I did not realise that would store the actual plaintext password.. wow.. Thanks so much for the help :)

Comment: Only for a fraction of second I think, so not really a security vulnerability, but surely an inefficient use of DB queries.